# request to https://registry.npmjs.org/co failed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

If I do `npm install` in my repository. I get the below error

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/co failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I tried with

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But it does not solve the problem

Please help to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this npm config set strict-ssl false. But it is not safe to do safe. You should only try if you cannot find a fix for it. I recommend you uninstall everything and then re-install it

Comment: @dnp1204 Do you want me to reinstall npm ?

Comment: I mean uninstall your nodejs and then reinstall it. It happened to me before. After I re-install node, everything works just fine. I am not sure it will work for you but you should give a try

Comment: Read this https://npm.community/t/common-proxy-and-networking-problems/151 if it does not work

Comment: @dnp1204 I reinstalled nodejs and did `npm config set strict-ssl false`. but didnot solve the problem. Still i get error. please see the error message in my comment below `gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)`

Comment: I just realized that the OS time and date are not up to date, So checking the automatic update in date settings solved the problem.

Answer (score 34):

This appears to be an issue with *attempting to use SSL while installing your project's required packages*. This occurs due to how you set your npm registry:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Notice the https prefix in your npm registry, **Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS)** is the **secure version of HTTP**, the protocol over which data is sent between your browser and the website that you are connected to. The **'S' at the end of HTTPS stands for 'Secure'**. It means all communications between your browser and the website are encrypted. HTTPS pages typically use one of **two secure protocols to encrypt communications - SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) or TLS (Transport Layer Security).**

Perhaps you can try the following to see if it resolves your issue:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then try reinstalling your dependencies with an `npm install`

Alternatively, you can **turn off the ssl requirement** (although use at your own discretion) by doing the following:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

then try to install your requirements again with an `npm install`

Comment: I reinstalled nodejs and did 'npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/' and  `npm config set strict-ssl false` but still i get the below error message. `gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)`

Comment: If you're on a WIN environment check out this link: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/979. They had to do the following: $ sudo npm install -g node-gyp
$ node-gyp configure
and then reinstalling the libraries with an npm install worked

Comment: I get this when I try to do `npm install` after setting it to `http`: `npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use
TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: h
ttps://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/`

Answer (score 7):

Removing package-lock.json file (and restarting build) solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably due to a proxy network. You can disable the proxy and run `npm install`
Or make sure you set the proxy configurations

```
npm config set https-proxy [address]:[port]
```

Then try `npm install` again

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue (just learning NodeJS for the first time). Turned out that I had a ZScaler issue.  I disabled it for the download and it worked.

Comment: Oh man this suggestion just saved me!! Thank you! 
Even just browsing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ would give me the ERR_CONNECTION in Edge, Firefox and Chrome. I too had ZScaler running. Turned it off and the site magically resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Our company VPN was causing this conflict. I disabled the VPN. Dave Girvitz tip about Zscaler led me to investigate the VPN.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how did u resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

change registry url if it is http from below command

```
npm config get registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

and also disable ipv6 ipv6 connectivity by going to the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can reach the link:
http://registry.npmjs.org/  or https://registry.npmjs.org/
then set registry as needed:
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

You night need to set it in your HOSTS file if it's not resolved.
If all is well so far, and after the  changes by @nathan above seems not to work, i suggest restarting the networking with:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service docker restart
```

then run you run npm build script again.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to cloudfare's DNS. Now, things are working fine.
You can use [this](https://privacy.net/set-up-cloudflare-dns-how-to/)

Answer (score 0):

Video Reference Youtube=> https://youtu.be/vzORm7AUUSQ

I have changed registry url from http to https like below , also cleaned the cache, removed proxy but nothing work.

npm config get registry https://registry.npmjs.org

The only things that work for me is disabling ipv6 connectivity by going to the control panel

Answer (score -2):

Disable your antivirus and try to install. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Connect to faster internet in order to install packages.